# Python Tkinter file dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a small python program with tkinter as the gui to select excel files and open them, I got to the point where I can select the file and open them. My problem is when the user dont't select a file and click cancel It produces and error.  How to continue code if the user does not select a file in tkinter file dialog?

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import sys
import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()


def getExcel():
    global df

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    df = pd.read_excel(import_file_path)
    book = load_workbook(import_file_path)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(import_file_path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    x3 = (df.loc[(df['Var Cost'] < -500) | (df['Var Cost'] > 500)])
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='VarianceSorted')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
    command = import_file_path
    os.system(command)


def end():
    sys.exit()


browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Import Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

quitbutton = tk.Button(text='Quit', command=end, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 200, window=quitbutton)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post your code and the full traceback, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @acw1668 , sorry just posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the returned `import_file_path` before proceeding:

```
def getExcel():
    global df

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if import_file_path:
        df = pd.read_excel(import_file_path)
        book = load_workbook(import_file_path)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(import_file_path, engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        x3 = (df.loc[(df['Var Cost'] < -500) | (df['Var Cost'] > 500)])
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3)
        df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='VarianceSorted')
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
        command = import_file_path
        os.system(command)
```

Comment: this worked perfectly , was also able to get a message box saying 'please select file'